# Unable to get PHP working with SQL Server in Docker Container

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Background: I'm very new to Docker and working with a team on a CodeIgniter application. The current version of the project is running in a Docker container using MySQL, but we are exploring moving to SQL Server.

When I run `docker build --no-cache .` everything seems to work with no errors, and I can connect to the database using HeidiSQL.

However, when I open the application in a browser, I get the:

> Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

error and if I pull up my test file with `phpinfo()` I do not see `sqlsrv` or `pdo_sqlsrv` anywhere.

I've done a lot of research online, sought help from team mates (all of us are Docker newbs), and even purchased and gone through tutorials but I haven't been able to solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I feel like I'm just overlooking something obvious.

Below are my `docker-compose.yaml` and `Dockerfile`. In the `Dockerfile` you can see 4 variations I've found online to try to get this working, but all of them have the same result.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    db_mssql:
        container_name: db_mssql
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU12-ubuntu-20.04
        environment:
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
            SA_PASSWORD: "Testing123"
            MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
        ports:
            - '1433:1433'
        volumes: 
            - mssql-volume:/var/opt/mssql

    app-cp-v3:
        build: .
        container_name: app-cp-v3
        ports:
            - 8090:80
        volumes:
            - ./app-cp-v3/:/var/www/html
        networks:
            - default
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        environment:
            XDEBUG_ENABLE: "true"
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost remote_port=9004 remote_autostart=1"

volumes:
    mssql-volume:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/html/public/html!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!/var/www/html/public/html!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nano wget gnupg2

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath sockets pcntl 

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.9.7
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.idekey=vscode" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
&& echo "xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
#RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - 
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev 
RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
RUN docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# V1
# Install MS ODBC Driver for SQL Server
#ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
#RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
#    && apt-get update \
#    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev \
#    && pecl install sqlsrv \
#    && pecl install pdo_sqlsrv \
#    && echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini \
#    && echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-sqlsrv.ini \
#    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*
#
# END V1

# V2
#
#ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
#RUN apt-get update \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list \
#        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
#    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
#        locales \
#        apt-transport-https \
#    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
#    && locale-gen \
#    && apt-get update \
#    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
#        unixodbc-dev \
#        msodbcsql17
#
#RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
#
# END V2

# V3
#
#RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
#
#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
#RUN apt-get update
#RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
# optional: for unixODBC development headers
#RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
#
# activate extensions in php.ini
#RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
#    && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
#
# END V3

# V4
#
# Microsoft SQL Server Prerequisites
#RUN apt-get update > /dev/null \
#    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg2 > /dev/null \
#    && apt-get update > /dev/null \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
#    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list \
#        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
#    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
#        locales \
#        apt-transport-https \
#        > /dev/null \
#    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
#    && locale-gen > /dev/null \
#    && apt-get update > /dev/null \
#    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
#        unixodbc-dev \
#        msodbcsql17 \
#        > /dev/null 
#    
# Install & enable Microsoft SQL Server
#RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo > /dev/null \
#    && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv > /dev/null \
#    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv > /dev/null 
#
#
# END V4

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: Are you sure that `app-cp-v3` is actually building? _A Dockerfile must begin with a FROM instruction._ [REF](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format)

Comment: Looks like I formatted the code block badly and it wasn't showing the first line: FROM php:7.3-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to run `docker-compose build app-cp-v3` instead of `docker build`.

When you use docker-compose with build instructions, it creates a docker image with its own name (a combination of folder name + service). This means if you use `docker build` without correct tag `docker-compose` uses the "old" image.

When you work with `docker-compose` my advice is to use also the `docker-compose` cli (for builds, pulls, etc.) over the `docker` cli to avoid such pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I figured this out on my own eventually, but the issue was exactly as ddegasperi suggested. I was re-using the old image rather than the newly built one.